# Returning elements from lists within a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am trying to select the first element from nested lists within a bigger list.  I am trying to return name values out of a MySQL table.  I establish a connection to the server and then I do the following:

```
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM prototype")
db.commit()
results = cur.fetchall()
for name in cur:
    print results[0]
```

I get the following output:

```
('orange', 50L, 3L)
('orange', 50L, 3L)
('orange', 50L, 3L)
('orange', 50L, 3L)
('orange', 50L, 3L)
('orange', 50L, 3L)
('orange', 50L, 3L)
('orange', 50L, 3L)
('orange', 50L, 3L)
('orange', 50L, 3L)
```

It is repeating for the correct number of entries, but only returning one entry.  How do I get it to return the name of each entry?  The full results are:

```
(('test', 3L, 1L), ('apple', 10L, 2L), ('orange', 50L, 3L), ('\tbanana', 1L,4L),     ('test1', 5L, 5L), ('test5', 5L, 6L), ('test3', 3L, 7L), ('gui', 1L, 8L), ('test10', 5L,  9L), ('screws', 10L, 10L))
```

Comment: You loop through `cur` with `name` and print `results[0]`?! You don't change `results` in your loop, that should explain why you get the same output 10 times.

Comment: I tried looping through  both `cur` and `results` while printing `results` and both variables returned the same result.

Comment: You make here a very basic mistake - looping through an object shouldn't change it. You just print the first item of the fetched results again and again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you should be looping your `results` like so:

```
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM prototype")
db.commit()
results = cur.fetchall()
for name in results:
    print name[0]
```

What you get with the code above is a `tuple` of tuples, so each iteration of the for loop, you assign each consecutive tuple to `name`. Now to retrieve values of that tuple, you call it's 1st element by `name[0]`, 2nd by `name[1]` and so on.

Comment: That worked.  Thank you very much.  I was trying to print results, not name.  Thank you for answering my dumb mistake.

Comment: Your welcome, and you should consider accepting this answer if it did help you.

Comment: It did, however I must wait to before it will let me accept it.

Comment: @sommerjj I didn't realize that, sorry. By the way, may I suggest having a read here http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkCSpy/html/chap09.html . Understanding objects in Python can be very beneficial in the long run :)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
for name in cur:
    print results[0]
```

to

```
for result in results:
    print result[0]
```

Comment: I think he wants to print `result[0]` ;)

Comment: Yep, just noticed and fixed that.